# Find Window "User Access Control Settings" / "Benutzerkontensteuerung" and Click No/Nein

Tags: c#, windows, appium, user-account-control

I must start an application and I must check that the application tells me it works with the correct signature.This information is shown via the "User Access Control" Dialog.

Because the system stops after **process.Start** I do this job in **backgroundWorker_DoWork**. The application starts fine, shows the "User Access Control" Dialog and my following code was found.

My problem is to find the window of "User Access Control" Dialog.

The code

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "Benutzerkontensteuerung");
```

finds no window. And

```
int HWND = 0;
EnumWindows(new EnumWindowCallBack(EnumWindowCallBack), HWND);
```

also finds no window with "Benutzerkontensteuerung".

Is there a chance to find this window, the find the message for the user and to send an Enter to it?

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to find it, the UAC prompt is displayed on the secure desktop.  For obvious reasons, the protection is bullet-proof.  At best you could ask for elevation for your own program so no UAC prompt has to be displayed for the invoked process, but that just moves the goal posts.

Comment: I have to write a test for a given software. The test has to check the correct signature usage via windows after a hack of the software.